How do I write a VBA excel macro to format graphs?
I found part of this macro online and copied it letter for letter. The video unfortunately cuts off the code so I can't see the bottom of the document. I tried to accomplish making a macro for the graph formatting originally by recording clicks but it didn't work. When I run this code it says "Compile error: Unexpected End with".
What can I do to make this code work?
Thanks
Sub PrettyGraph()
'PrettyGraph Macro
'

    With ActiveChart
        
            ' Make chart big and square-ish / prevent resiziing with cells
            ' THIS WILL NOT WORK IF CHART IS ON ITS OWN WORKSHEET
            .Parent.Placement = x1Move
            .Parent.Height = 300
            .Parent.Width = 350
            
            ' Remove black border around the whole chart
            .ChartArea.Border.LineStyle = x1None
            
            ' Font: eliminate autoscaling / set size to 12
            .ChartArea.AutoScaleFont = False
            .ChartArea.Font.Size = 12
            
            ' Plot Area: fill whole chart / change grey to white
            .PlotArea.Top = 0
            .PlotArea.Left = 20 'allow room for y-axis label
            .PlotArea.Width = 320 'make square-ish
            .ChartArea.Fill.Visible = msoTrue
            .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 2 ' white
            .PlotArea.Border.ColorIndex = 1 ' black
            .PlotArea.Format.Line.Weight = 1


            ' Axis Titles: add bold / adjust position
            ' x-axis (don't add titles if already present)
            If Not .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle Then
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Time (uS)"
            End If
            .Axes(xlCategory).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
            ' y-axis (don't add titles if already present)
            If Not .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle Then
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
                .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Load (N)"
            End If
            .Axes(xlValue).AxisTitle.Font.Bold = True
            
            ' Gridlilnes: remove major on y-axis
            .Axes(xlValue).HasMajorGridlines = False
            .Axes(xlCategory).HasMajorGridlines = False
            
            'Tickmarks: black / inside / linewidth to thin / general number
            'x-axis
            .Axes(xlCategory).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' black
            .Axes(xlCategory).MajorTickMark = xlInside
            .Axes(xlCategory).Border.Weight = xlThin
            .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General"
            .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
            
            'y-axis
            .Axes(xlValue).Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(0, 0, 0) ' black
            .Axes(xlValue).MajorTickMark = xlInside
            .Axes(xlValue).Border.Weight = xlThin
            .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "General"
            .Axes(xlValue).TickLabelPosition = xlLow
            
End Sub


Try to add an End With before the End Sub line. See also (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/with-statement)
